# How to eliminate a fraction from this matrix im trying to invert?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have as far as I have shown in the picture, however I do not know how to get rid of the 3rd column above the 1. I`ve tried a couple of ways but I have only ended up messing up other columns.

[image]

I appreciate any help given!

Comment: What is the context of this picture? It kind of looks like writing a matrix in reduced-row echelon form...

Comment: Oh, you are finding the inverse of a matrix! Got it... How did you create the zeros in the left columns $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well enough, I went onto an online calculator for inverting matrices but I do not kno how to get rid of the 1/3 and -2/3 in the 3rd column.

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix row operations?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with them, i am just not too sure how to get rid of the 3rd column with the fractions involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint - Operate following operations.

$Row_1 - \frac 13 Row_3$

$Row_2 + \frac 23 Row_3$

Comment: I think you have errors with your signs.

Comment: @Tim Thayer no chance. If still then where?

Comment: My mistake. I was looking at the wrong matrix. Sorry!

Comment: @amar that completely went over my head, I didnt think it was that easy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tim Thayer it's ok.

Comment: Mine pleasure bro.

Answer (score 0):

- For the **first row**: multiply the third row by -1/3, and sum the first and third row. Then multiply the third row by -3.
- For the **second row**: multiply the third row by 3/2, and sum the second and third row. Then multiply the third row by 2/3.